# SBT "unforced update" command

Tags: sbt

The ["update" task in SBT is smart](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Dependency-Management-Flow.html).  `update` doesn't resolve dependencies unless it needs to if it's a task dependency.  However, if you run `sbt update` explicitly it forces the resolution of all artifacts.

Is there a task I can run that will download needed artifacts but not re-resolve artifacts that are already cached?  I need this to populate the cache of our continuous build system.  If the cache is already filled, I don't want to force the re-resolution of all the artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

`transitiveUpdate` seems to do the trick.